# Why du command show different total in folder versus in parent

Tags: linux, du, disk-access

I can't understand why I have different total size in a folder versus in parent.

That's my folder tree

```
bkp
|-- raid10
|    |-- folder_a 
|    |-- folder_b 
|    |-- folder_c 
|    |-- folder_d 
|    |-- folder_e 
|    |-- folder_f 
|    |-- folder_g 
|    |-- folder_h 
|    |-- folder_i 
|    |-- folder_j 
|    |-- folder_k 
|    |-- folder_l
|    |-- script.sh
|-- vm
```

I previously delete a big amount of file in that folder and I want to get my new disk usage.

```
sudo du -shc /bkp/*
756G    raid10
4.0K    vm
756G    total
```

Now I execute that command to get more info about the folder raid10:

```
sudo du -shc /bkp/raid10/*
13G     folder_a
178M    folder_b
15G     folder_c
2.3G    folder_d
32M     folder_e
31G     folder_f
31G     folder_g
49G     folder_h
131M    folder_i
4.7G    folder_j
392M    folder_k
4.0K    folder_l
4.0K    lost+found
4.0K    script.sh~
144G    total
```

Why the total is so different ?

I checked `man du` and tried some command, like `--apparent-size`, but same result. Also try without -s `sudo du -hc /bkp/raid10/*`, I have the same total but I see all directory...

I have some assumptions:

- There is some cache in `du` command ?
- There is a trash or hidden file that `du` can't read?

Some information about my files:

- Disk filesystem is ext4
- File are uploaded with rsync
- Disk is not in raid

Comment: Any files starting with "." (dot character) inside the raid10 directory? Can you do `ls -al` inside the raid10 directory and see. Or you could run `find . -name ".*" -ls` to find such dirs/files recursively.

Comment: @blackpen Thank, I found my problem, I have a .trash-1000 folder in my raid10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make `du` search for invisible just do:

```
#First part will get all invisible and second will get all non-invisible
du -shc /bkp/raid10/.[!.]* /bkp/raid10/*
```

Or cleaner command:

```
cd /bkp/raid10
du -sch .[!.]* *
```

Or enable shell option that matches hidden file with globbing

```
shopt -s dotglob
du -sch *
```

Comment: Good one. Were you trying to find disk usage for hidden dirs/files only in /bkp/raid10 directory (OR also in current directory)? May be you want it as `/bkp/raid10/.[!.]*` ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, my command is not good, I will edit for cleaner response. It's work because i'm in /bkp/raid10.

Comment: Or just enable the shell option that matches hidden files with globbing (e.g. `dotglob` on bash).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thank for another alternative I will add

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, Good one!

Answer (score 0):

To look for hidden (names starting with a dot) files/directories recursively:

```
find . -name ".*" -ls
```